# Pascal variables representation on the machine

Tags: pascal

I was given a question in my homework.
How the pascal variables represented on the machine?
for example: in C it can be different on different machines and compilers, in java there is a VM, so the programmer can assume he will get the exact same representation on different machines.

I have been googling for a while and could not find an answer about pascal. The question is about the original version of pascal, if it changer something.

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe one of your classmates took notes on this topic when it was covered in class?

Comment: Pascal is very similar to C in the way it implements lower level concepts such as variables.

Comment: H2CO3: only later Pascal derivatives like TP do. Pascal originally was much more abstract, was mostly safe and VMable.

Answer (score 1):

Original (J&W) Pascal is extremely rare, and most people don't know it. It got cleaned up a bit into the ISO 7185 standard, though those changes IIRC mostly affect scoping and type equivalence, not the kind of types.

Original (non UCSD, over a decade before Borland/Turbo dialects) Pascal has nearly no machine dependent types. Just one type INTEGER and one floating point type, REAL, and non integer ordinal types like enums, boolean and char. Char was not guaranteed 8-bit, the with dependent on the machine word.

Pascal shows his mainframe roots here, where words had exotic sizes like 60-bit, didn't allow subword acess (say bytelevel access, but that is a stretch, since they might not know the concept of byte), and multiple chars were packed into machinewords. (see packed array below). C was several years later, and targeted minis, so avoided the worst of that legacy.

The integer type is the biggest type in the system, quite often the biggest type that the machine can do conveniently. Smaller integer sizes are constructed with subranges, there are no unsigned types, but these can be defined with relevant subranges (and it is up to the compiler/VM to implement those efficiently)

e..g  BYTE= 0..255;

Arrays can be packed, and must be unpacked before use (with pack() and unpack()).

There is no stringtype, typically packed fixed size array of char is used, with right padding with space to signal endofstring (so trailing spaces is hard, but it is only a convention, and not much runtime support, so in exceptional cases, you simply make an exception)

Unions contain all components as separate fields (no overlap) and are always named.

It had pointers, but you couldn't take addresses of arbitrary symbols, and new pointers could only be created with NEW.

So in general original Pascal is what you would call a reasonably "safe" language, though it was not fully designed as such (and afaik not 100% safe in theory. It was also much more suitable for VMing than TP (and that happened with UCSD, albeit for a subset).

Pascal and its successors can be considered as reconnaissance of concepts that were later popularized with Java.

Answer (score 0):

In C it can be different on different machines and compilers, so are they in Pascal, of course.